# React/React Native: Changes in a child component's state re-render entire components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

Here is the simple representation of the code of the component:

```
/*
All the necessary imports
*/


export default function ParentComponent() {
    const [parentState, setParentState] = useState(null);
    const {username, setUsername} = useContext(Username);

    const route = useRoute();
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    useEffect(()=>{
        //Logic to call setParentstate based on query results;
    })

    const FirstComponent = () => {
        const [firstState, setFirstState] = useState(null);

        useEffect(()=>{
            //Logic to call setFirststate based on query results;
        },[])
    
        return (
            <View>
               <Text>{firstState}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    };

    const SecondComponent = () => {
        const [secondState, setSecondState] = useState(0);
        const {number, setNumber} = useContext(Number);

        useEffect(()=>{
            //Logic to call setSecondstate and setNumber based on query results;
        },[])
    
        const updateState = () => {
            setSecondState(secondState + 1);
            setNumber(secondState + 1);
        };
    
        return (
            <View>
               <Text>{secondState}</Text>
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={updateState}>
                   <Text>Update</Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    };

    return (
    <View>
        <Text>{username}</Text>
        <Text>{parentState}</Text>
        <FirstComponent />
        <SecondComponent />
    </View>
    );
}
```

There is a functionality to update state and reflect the change on the SecondComponent. Since I am not changing the ParentComponent's state, this should not trigger re-rendering of the ParentComponent. However, all of the components get re-rendered when the secondState is updated.

I am confused because updates in the state of the child component should not trigger re-rendering of the parent component, but this keeps happening.

I suspect this has to do with hooks in the parent component or use of Context API, but am not sure.

Can anyone help me out in identifying what might be causing this, and how I should fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Regardless of any other issue you surely don't want to define `FirstComponent` and `SecondComponent` in the body of `ParentComponent` as anytime `ParentComponent` rerenders then the child components will be redeclared, the previous components will unmount and new ones mounted.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-react-native-changes-in-a-child-components-state-re-render-entire-compon-kn810) and I don't reproduce the issue you describe. I did have to comment out the context code though since you didn't provide it. Can you update your question to include all relevant code?

Comment: I think defining `FirstComponent` and `SecondComponent` outside the `ParentComponent` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a similar issue, it was solved by defining just one component per file.